# How to wait a function finishes and pass variable between files in Roku BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm building a Roku channel and I'm facing a problem where I need a function to finish in order to run the lines afterwards & also I cant figure how to access a variable between components, this is the flow I have:

file1.brs

```
MainFunction.observeField("itemSelected", "func1") -first wait for this to finish
MainFunction.observeField("itemSelected", "func2") -then run this

sub func2()
    print var1
end sub
```

file2.brs

```
sub func1()
    var1 = (get content from some database)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Observers all fire independently of each other, so you will need to call `func2` from inside `func1`.

Also, every roku component has its own copy of `m`, which is a global AA unique for each instance of the component. (similar to `this` in other languages). So you could share data between `func1` and `func1` like this:

`file1.brs`

```vb
MainFunction.observeField("itemSelected", "func1")

sub func2()
    print m.var1
end sub
```

`file2.brs`

```vb
sub func1()
    m.var1 = (get content from some database)
    func2()
end sub
```